# Keep selection in highcharts even on page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, highcharts

I am using highcharts for generating/showcasing graph on UI(HTML with JavaScript Page)

There are multiple elements in series section that one can select or unselect to display on graph.
But after every refresh, user selected elements gets unselected and only the default selections appear. And user has to select the elements again.

Any solution to it?

One can relate the question from the picture:
[image]

In this, By default A is selected.
If user selects Ball or C then the point graph will appear for Ball and C as well but as soon as graph refreshes, graph will have point graph with A only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your visible series states in local storage. Example:

```
const savedStates = localStorage.getItem('seriesStates');
const seriesStates = savedStates ?
    JSON.parse(savedStates) : {
        A: true,
        Ball: false,
        C: false,
        D: false
    };

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        name: 'A',
        data: [1, 2, 3],
        visible: seriesStates.A
    }, {
        name: 'Ball',
        data: [2, 2, 2],
        visible: seriesStates.Ball
    }, {
        name: 'C',
        data: [3, 3, 3],
        visible: seriesStates.C
    }, {
        name: 'D',
        data: [4, 4, 4],
        visible: seriesStates.D
    }],
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function() {
                    seriesStates[this.name] = !this.visible;
                    localStorage.setItem(
                        'seriesStates',
                        JSON.stringify(seriesStates)
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jkuc50Lf/

**Docs:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage